# working with global variable with multiple repetition in filemaker pro 10

Tags: filemaker

Hi all i have declared a global vriable with 2 repetition,

**set variable [$$arr[2];value:"9557878322"]**

as i know i have declared it with 2 repetition so that it should store maximum two value but i dont know how to insert multiple value when we declare global variable with more then 1 repetition.

what i want : declare global variable with repetition 2
              it will look like $$arr[2]
              i want to insert two values so that arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faO9o.png) refer first value and arr[2] refer 2nd value......

Here i have entered a snap where u can see thet i have declared repetition 2..

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy using valuelists, then you don't need a 2 repetition variable. Instead once you've set your $arr as you've shown in the screen shot, just use

> MiddleValues ( $$arr ; index ; 1 )

to retrieve the the value at [index] (remembering that it will have a return attached), and

> $$arr = $newValue & ¶ & RightValues ( $$arr ; 1 )

to set the first value, or

> $$arr = LeftValues ( $$arr ; 1 ) & ¶ & $newValue

to set the second value.

HOWEVER, I suspect you might be better off altogether taking a look at [Passing Named Parameters](http://sixfriedrice.com/wp/passing-multiple-parameters-to-scripts-advanced/) and [Dictionary Functions](http://sixfriedrice.com/wp/filemaker-dictionary-functions/) which outline some useful tricks for storing values in dictionaries - there are a whole slew of custom functions that you'll probably find useful for working with associative arrays in FileMaker.

You're assignment in your dialog box might look something like:

> Name: $arr 
>   Value: #("1" , 9557878322 ) & #("2" , 8430695900 )

and the values could be retrieved as

> #?($arr , "1")

or

> #?($arr , "2")

or reset using

> #c($arr, "1" , 1234 )

The syntax of these new custom functions ( # , #? and #c ) takes a bit to get used to, but it may be the sort of things that you could use for this task, but which would also broaden how you use calcs in FileMaker in the future too. Or not ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use the Set Variable step twice or set the values within a Let statement:

```
Let( [ 
    $arr[1] = "Value 1"; 
    $arr[2] = "Value 2" ];
  "" )
```

You can use either a dummy statement as above or make it a part of a some other step.

Comment: Can u tell me what repetition will do here, i means during global variable declaration.why it's need

Comment: @Nishant In FileMaker you can't initialize an entire array in one step, as you are trying to do in the screenshot in the question. Instead you must instantiate each item in the array separately. In a script the easiest way to think about this would be to have two Set Variable script steps.  With one being var:$$arr, val:9557878322, rep:1 and theother being var:$$arr, val:8430695900, rep:2